# How to add a list of "permitted values" to a parameter by using a BigQuery connector in Data Studio?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, parameters, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I was wondering if there is a way to add a list of "permitted values" to a parameter in Data Studio by using a custom query / BigQuery connector?

There is an option to do it manually in the Data Studio UI:
[Permitted values through Data Studio UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdPyh.png)

But I am looking for a solution to do it through SQL because I have to pass a long list of values that can be changed every day, so adding a list of values manually through the UI is impossible.

Is it possible to do it through a custom query?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add parameters to a custom SQL query in the connector, just like the following examples show

```
    SELECT word FROM `TABLE` WHERE corpus = @corpus;
    
    Use a string with contains and a number:
    
    SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.baseball.games_post_wide`
    
    WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(gameId, @s)
    
    AND attendance > @attendance LIMIT 100;

    
    Use a multi-select string parameter. Note the use of UNNEST to flatten the list of values:
    
    SELECT * from user.users as user WHERE display_name in UNNEST(@name);

    
    Date parameter example:
    
    SELECT creation_date, age, display_name from user.users as user
    
    WHERE creation_date > PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_START_DATE)
    
    AND creation_date < PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE);

    
    Email parameter example:
    
    Select * from Sales WHERE sales-rep-email = @DS_USER_EMAIL;
```

[Here](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9002005?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) you can read more about using parameters in Data Studio

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a custom query to define allowed Values if you want to Filter for them just set them up as a Dimension and add a Filter Control with an drop-down List. This will allow you to  select the present Values and filter for them.

Let me know if this solves it for you

Comment: Hi Aleko, in my case I do need to use a custom query with parameters.
The question is if I can use a drop-down list with a lot of values, and when you choose multiple values, they are inserted into the parameter I defined in the custom query.

I believe I can do it only when you define "permitted values" for the parameter. But doing it manually and inserting a huge amount of values is impossible.

I am hoping there is a way to do it by SQL.